# Can I use function macros inside gcc inline assembly block?

Tags: gcc, assembly, macros

```
#define MOV_MACRO(R0,R1)\
{\
    "mov R0, R1 \n\t"\                                                      
}

__asm__ volatile(\
    MOV_MACRO(r4,r5)
    :"r4","r5"\
    );\
```

Is it possible to use a function like this in an asm block ?
If not, please suggest ways to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but if you need such functionality you probably shouldn't be using inline asm but a separate asm module.

```
#define MOV_MACRO(R0,R1) "mov " #R0 ", " #R1 "\n\t"

void foo()
{
__asm__ volatile(
    MOV_MACRO(r4,r5)
    ::
    :"r4","r5"
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you pls answer why it shouldn't be inline asm ?

Comment: Inline asm should generally be used for short, simple pieces of code where a function call would be impossible or have significant overhead. If you need macros that seems to indicate your code is more complex than that. Of course there are exceptions, it's just a general guideline.